# How to calculate conditional expectation explicitly?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a question about the conditional expectation.

Let $X_1$, ... $X_n$ be random sample from $B(1,p)$ ,the usual Bernoulli trial. Let $T= \sum_{j=1}^n X_j$ and let $U(X_1, ..., X_n) := 1_{(X_1=X_2=1)}$.

I want to compute $E(U|T=t)$ explicitly in order to find the UMVUE of $p^2$.
But I can't even compute the joint probability density function of $U$ and $T$.

Please help me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In words, $E(U\mid T=t) = P(X_1 = X_2 = 1 \mid T=t)$ equals the probability that the first two trials were success given you saw $t$ successes in $n$ independent trials.

- For $t=0$ and $t=1$ the conditional probability is clearly zero.
- For $t\ge 2$, this is a counting exercise. By symmetry, there are ${n\choose t}$ equally likely ways to distribute $t$ successes among the $n$ trials. To have the first 2 trials be success means that the remaining $t-2$ successes must be distributed among the remaining $n-2$ trials; there are ${n-2\choose t-2}$ ways to do this, so
  $$E(U\mid T=t)=\frac{n-2\choose t-2}{n\choose t}.\tag1$$
  Now simplify (1) by writing out $n\choose k$ in terms of factorials.